# applescript strange behaviour with rename file script

Tags: image, applescript, filenames, rename

I wrote this simple script that changes filenames of the folder Images on my desktop. The script works on the first run, however when I rerun it with a different string for the variable newName (same string would throw error: filename already exists). It only changes the name of the even numbers of "item x of the Folder".
Can someone enlighten me on how this happens and what to do to avoid this peculiar behaviour. I'm having a hard time figuring this out.
Thank you very much in advance.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFolder to ((path to desktop folder) & "Images") as string as alias
    set myImages to the name of every file of theFolder
    set indexOfFolder to (count items in myImages) as number
    set newName to "whateverName" as string

    repeat with x from 1 to indexOfFolder
        set name of item x of theFolder to newName & x & ".JPG"
    end repeat
end tell
```

edit: After some more testing, it appears that the problem would not point exclusively to unchanged uneven numbers. With more then 20 files it appears to switch from 20 on to the even numbers that will not be renamed.

Comment: Can you explain in English what the script is actually supposed to do? At the moment, all I can see is that it doesn't work but I have no idea what it needs to do in order to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are working on the name of the Folder, and also the chars of the folder (items of the folder)

Please compare with this that should work correctly:

```
 tell application "Finder"
    set theFolder to ((path to desktop folder as text) & "Images")
    set myImages to the name of every file of folder theFolder
    set indexOfFolder to (count myImages)

    set newname to "Z picture " as string

    repeat with x from 1 to indexOfFolder
        set name of item x of folder theFolder to newname & x & ".JPG"
    end repeat
 end tell
```

It still isn't bug free, next discrepancy is that you use files, when gathering the contents into the `myImages` variable, but you address the item of the folder, which are two different object classes. I have also, finally set the folder as the in this last implementation, to avoid redundancy. Pleas also observe where I have placed the coercions, and which I have removed, because they were redundant.

```
 tell application "Finder"
    set theFolder to folder ((path to desktop folder as text) & "Images")
    set myImages to the name of every file of theFolder
    set indexOfFolder to (count myImages)

    set newname to "Z picture " as string

    repeat with x from 1 to indexOfFolder
        set name of file x of theFolder to newname & x & ".JPG"
    end repeat
 end tell
```

This version, should work even though when files changes names, as the file-list is obtained up front.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFolder to folder ((path to desktop folder as text) & "Images")
    set myImages to every file of theFolder
    set indexOfFolder to (count myImages)

    set newname to "Z picture " as string

    repeat with x from 1 to indexOfFolder
        set name of item x of myImages to newname & x & ".JPG"
    end repeat
  end tell
```

Comment: What do you mean by "identical results"? With your script?

Comment: Hi McUsr Thanks for your reply!
I have tested your script and came up with very identical results.
With the first 20 files the uneven numbers are changed and from 20 on the even numbers will get changed.
Any idea why this would work half the time?

Comment: I have no idea, the second version of the script, changed all filenames, to filenames with numbers when I ran it, the files hadn't any numbers from before. Have you been running the script on files without a number?

Comment: Actually, one reason for the behaviour you experience, may be that the file x, may change over the course while you run the script, (when the file is renamed, it may change place), when you address a file like file nr x, then everything happens dynamically, like: file nr5 when the folder is sorted ascending is different from file nr 5 when the folder is sorted descendent.

Comment: I have added one last version, to my answer, that should work as intended, because it gathers the file-list up front, and therefore are robust to the renaming of files. If this works for you, please check off for answered to the left of the post containing the answer. :)

Comment: Indeed this one does the trick flawlessly!
Thank you very much for your suggestions, greatly appreciated.
It looks very much indeed like the position of x would get changed and therefore some files would get skipped.